# How to deploy docker image with gitlab CI and portainer

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I know Kubernetes has rest API to automate deploy docker image on it. and i know how to use it by Gitlab runner. I wonder if portainer has this feature to call a rest API and deploy my image on it ?
I mean how to use recreate container or create container like in portainer ui as a pi service ?
Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do, it add a stack to portainer that gets its docker-compose file from your gitlab git repository. Of course you need to add your gitlab registry as a docker registry to portainer first.

Comment: Bart does it grab the rest of the repo as well (like Dockerfiles for images referenced in the docker-compose file using build/context), or is it just the docker-compose file that gets pulled?

Comment: Thank you Bart for giving some hope to a tired old man! Going to play with it tonight

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to add my repo as a container or as an image and it wasn't working. You have to add it as a stack.